Countable translations of a positive measure set cover an interval?
If $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with positive Lebesgue measure. Does there exist a countable sequence $\{t_i\} (i \in \mathbb{N})$ such that the union
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} (t_i+A)$$
contains an open interval?

No, let $A$ be a ``fat'' Cantor set which has positive measure but whose complement is open and dense. Then for any sequence $(t_i)$ the complement of $\bigcup (t_i + A)$ is a countable intersection of open dense sets and hence is dense. So $\bigcup (t_i + A)$ cannot contain any interval.
